# Can UNUserNotificationCenter.getDeliveredNotifications() be used to retrieve user-directed push notifications

Tags: ios

If a server sends a push notification to the user, but the user does not tap on that notification, can the app still determine that there was a push delivered to the handset and obtain the push payload using UNUserNotificationCenter.getDeliveredNotifications(), or is this method only for retrieving local notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649520-getdeliverednotifications):

> **notifications**
>
> An array of UNNotification objects representing the
>   local **and remote** notifications of your app that have been delivered
>   and are still visible in Notification Center. If none of your app’s
>   notifications are visible in Notification Center, the array is empty.

So, yes it will return also push notifications not opened yet and visible in Notification Center.